# java -jar "org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.0.v20130529-1710.jar" -consoleLog : Unable to acquire application service

Tags: equinox

I am trying to start up the equinox framework, similar to [here](http://eclipse.org/equinox/documents/quickstart-framework.php):

```
java -jar "org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.0.v20130529-1710.jar" -consoleLog
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
!SESSION 2013-07-04 22:49:46.256 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_25
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-07-04 22:49:46.692
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini)    .
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:152)
```

**Question:** Are there any more recent instructions for eclipse equinox osgi framework 3.9.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the command to:

```
java -jar "org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.0.v20130529-1710.jar" -consoleLog -console -configuration=C:\Dev\configuration\config.ini
```

The config.ini file:

```
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:C\:/Dev/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.0.201307051018.jar@start,reference\:file\:C\:/Dev/configuration/org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime-0.8.0.jar@start,reference\:file\:C\:/Dev/configuration/org.apache.felix.gogo.shell-0.8.0.jar@start,,reference\:file\:C\:/Dev/configuration/org.apache.felix.gogo.command-0.8.0.jar@start
```

I downloaded:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.gogo.shell/0.8.0/org.apache.felix.gogo.shell-0.8.0.jar
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.gogo.command/0.8.0/org.apache.felix.gogo.command-0.8.0.jar
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime/0.8.0/org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime-0.8.0.jar

I checked out the source for `org.eclipse.equinox.console` and built using eclipse.
The source was checked out from here: `git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/equinox/rt.equinox.bundles.git`.
Note that the timestamp (201307051018) in the filename in the config.ini was the time I built the jar.

Starting still gave me an error message, but this time I had the gogo shell:

```
!SESSION 2013-07-05 14:15:41.837 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_25
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -configuration=C:\Dev\configuration\config.ini
Command-line arguments:  -consoleLog -configuration=C:\Dev\configuration\config.ini -console

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-07-05 14:15:42.479
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:199)
bundleresource://8.fwk501544898/gosh_profile: ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Command name evaluates to null: ${.context} bundle 0
g! ss
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.0.qualifier
6   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.0.201307051018
7   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0
8   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0
9   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0
g!
```

Adding `eclipse.ignoreApp=true` to `config.ini` removed the IllegalStateException, resulting in:

```
Debug options:
    file:/C:/Dev/eclipse_source/rt.equinox.framework/bundles/org.eclipse.osgi/.options loaded
Time to load bundles: 12
bundleresource://8.fwk516992923/gosh_profile: ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Command name evaluates to null: ${.context} bundle 0
g! ss
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.0.qualifier
6   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.0.201307051018
7   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0
8   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0
9   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0
g!
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this one:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371101
and it seems the official docs seems to be wrong. Doing

```
java -jar -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20140110-1610.jar -console
```

Which works on my machine. Java 1.7.0_55